# How to watch pgrep?

Tags: process, ps, watch

When running a `pgrep` command with `watch` it does not only show the actual pgrep output, but also the `watch` process as well.

Example:

```
watch pgrep -lf donothing
```

will show 3 processes, although

```
pgrep -lf donothing
```

does not show one.  Is thee an elegant way to handle this properly with `watch` to not display the *own* process of `watch`?

EDIT

Using the suggestions by Patrick:

```
watch pgrep -f '^python donothing.py'
```

shows me the usage of `pgrep` (updated every 2 seconds...)

```
watch pgrep -l 'python donothing.py'
```

as well (the `pgrep` commands alone DO work but not in connection with `watch`).

```
watch "pgrep 'python donothing.py'"
```

does not show anything, although the process is there.

Comment: Adjust the `pgrep` to not use `-f`. If you're matching the command name, you should use no dash-argument at all, or `-x`, not `-f`.

Comment: I tried `watch -n 1 pgrep 'python donothing.py'` which lists a `pgrep` error, while the actual `pgrep` command is fine. I do not understand.

Comment: `pgrep donothing.py` or `pgrep -x donothing.py`

Answer (score 1):

From your comment you should be doing `pgrep donothing.py` or `pgrep -x donothing.py`.

When using `pgrep -f` it looks for any command which has the matching string in it's name and/or arguments. There is no pretty way of filtering out results. The solution is to match exactly what you're after, so match the process name.
`pgrep` by default matches just the process name. By default it will search for any process who's name contains the match string. With `-x` it will search for any process who's name exactly matches the string.

`pgrep` is also smart enough to understand scripts. If you have a script called `foo.sh`, it will show up in `ps` as `/bin/sh foo.sh` (or something similar). In this case `pgrep` will instead compare the script name. So you can do `pgrep foo.sh` or `pgrep -x foo.sh`.

So in your case, you should be doing `pgrep -x donothing.py` to get an exact match.

EDIT:
I should note that this only works if the script was launched as `/path/to/donothing.py`. If you launch it as `python donothing.py` it will not work.

In this case you need to use a regex like `pgrep -f '^python donothing.py'`.

EDIT2:
The problem you're encountering with `watch` is quoting. running `watch pgrep -f '^python donothing.py'` runs `pgrep` with no arguments. The `-f '^python donothing.py'` is passed as an argument to `watch`, not `pgrep` as intended. The whole pgrep command should be quoted.

```
watch "pgrep -f '^python donothing.py'"
```

As another note. If you are going to use this for other stuff, it might safer to do

```
watch "pgrep -f '(^|\S+/)python donothing.py'"
```

This will catch the case where the process shows up as something like `/usr/bin/python` instead of just `python`.

Comment: The command I am looking for is `python donothing.py`, with which your suggestion does not work.

Comment: @Alex updated answer. See the bit after "EDIT"

Comment: Thanks for the update, but the regex expression will not work with `watch` (it works as `pgrep` standalone, though).

Comment: @Alex if it works with `pgrep` but not `watch` then youre doing something wrong with `watch`. Can you update your question with the full command you're trying to run. Always provide specifics :-)

Comment: provided specifics, see updated question.

Comment: @alex updated answer. Works perfectly for me when I launch `python donothing.py`.